# No database selected - php and phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to connect my php code to my database and once I input and submit things like username, email address, and password in my html form. They will be sent to my database and shown in specific columns and there will be text like "New record has been created successfully" on my page. But for now, an error occurs instead.

The following is my php code

```
<?php
$visitorname = $emailaddress = $visitorpassword = $confirmpassword = "";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "mydb";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
$visitorname = input($_POST["visitorname"]);
$emailaddress = input($_POST["emailaddress"]);
$visitorpassword = input($_POST["visitorpassword"]);
$confirmpassword = input($_POST["confirmpassword"]);
$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
}



function input($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
if($visitorpassword == $confirmpassword){


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
$sql = "INSERT INTO registereduser (id, username, emailaddress, 
hashedpassword) VALUES ($id, $visitorname, $emailaddress, 
$hashed_password)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){

    echo "New record created successfully";
}else{
    echo "Errors " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
}else{
    echo "Passwords do not match";
}
?>
```

The following is the error output shown on my web page:

Connected successfullyErrors INSERT INTO registereduser (id, username, emailaddress, hashedpassword) VALUES (0, Josh5577, josh1998@hotmail.com, $2y$10$RMasEdVOskmcXbmfchLeBeUzLa5l38jXFaCQN7vMEhR8A0mU/iiC6)
No database selected

Comment: Are you giving the connection a password to connect with as well?$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

Comment: Yes I wanted to, but if I set username and password for logging into phpmyadmin. Then another error would show on the page. You may disregard the variables $username and $password I guess.

Comment: Can you add the error as text and not as image?

Comment: I have changed it to text now.

Comment: If you are still getting errors, it's probably because your credentials are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code for connection

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Comment: It gives me an error "Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in (my file location) in line "x"
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: It means you are not entering correct credentials 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "mydb";

Please check these credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbname);
```

to

```
// Create connection
$conn =  new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);
```

Comment: I tried it, but instead it shows this error "Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" and "Warning: mysqli_select_db(): Couldn't fetch mysqli".

Comment: It sounds to me like you are trying to connect to the DB with wrong credentials, cause you get Access denied followed by couldn´t fetch.

are you using the right credentials? you can check phpmyadmin or cPanel